# FileInputStream can not read file always

Tags: android-studio, directory, fileinputstream

I try to read a `.raw` audio file from the Android External Storage directory by using `FileInputStream`. Sometimes, I can read the file, sometimes not. What is the reason for this case?

Any help will be appreciated.

```java
storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
enrollWavPath = storageDir + 1 + ".raw";

File file = new File(enrollRawPath);
byte[] byteData = null;
int size = (int) file.length();
byteData = new byte[(int)(size)];
FileInputStream iFileStream = new FileInputStream(file);

int bytesread = 0;
int ret = 0;
while (bytesread < size) {
    ret = iFileStream.read( byteData,0, 2*count);
    if (ret != -1) {
        shortData = byte2short(byteData);
        bytesread += ret;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

iFileStream.close();
```